# What new DataAnnotations are included in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm reading about enhacements in ASP.NET MVC 2, and as we see, there is a topic about "Support for DataAnnotations Attributes": RangeAttribute, RequiredAttribute, StringLengthAttribute, and RegexAttribute. Were they available in MVC v1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataAnnotations` attributes lie in namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. The **ASP.NET MVC 2** includes built in support for the DataAnnotation validation. **ASP.NET MVC 1** not support built in DataAnnotation support(for validation), it needs Data Annotations Model Binder as described **[here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)**.